# How to rotate DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to rotate the DF but it doesn't want to arrange itself the way I want it to.
This is my DF:

```
wbp l    45
wbp ml   7
wbp k    27
wbp mk   37
bpz l    22
bpz ml   34
bpz k    12
bpz mk   41
pmh l    35
pmh ml   13
pmh k    9
pmh mk   44
```

I want to rotate DF like this:

```
      l    ml    k    mk
wbp  45    7     27   37 
bpz  22    34    12   41
pmh  35    13    9    44
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your column names for those three columns are: `A, B, C` and your dataframe is called `df`

```py
df.pivot(index='A', columns='B', values='C')
```